# mergAndroid Livecode- scanning barcode

Tags: android, mobile-application, livecode

I'm using mergZXingGetBarcode (mergAndroid) on Livecode to build an Android app that basically requires user to scan QR to login.

If the user device is not installed with the specific barcode scanner developed by ZXing Team, when the scan button is clicked, it looks as though there is no function being carried out (in user's view). Other 3rd party barcode scanners will not be triggered/detected.

Is there a way that I can detect that the ZXing Barcode is not installed and thus inform the user to install, or is there other barcode services that integrates with LiveCode (just like mergZXing with iOS app)?

Comment: I'm releasing mergZXing for android this week and it includes a function to do work out if a comparable scanner is available to use before mergZXingGetBarcode.

Comment: It's great to hear that! Thanks, Monte.