# mergeAV barcode scanning on android

Tags: android, porting, livecode

I tried `mergAVCamStartBarcodeReader`, `mergAVCamStopBarcodeReader` and `mergAVCamBarcodeFound` in LiveCode Indy version 8.1.1. with target platform Android. I could not get it working (does nothing).

On the Livecode Forum Mickey advised me to ask Monte to see if he has plans to port it. Within the same reply Mickey posted: 'As of today, mergAV doesn't run on Android.'

I am pretty disappointed because scanning bar- and QR-codes from within livecode is pretty important for me as it is a major part of a piece of business software I am developing a prototype for. Also having a livecode embedded solution for only one platform (IOS) goes agains one of LiveCodes main USP's *(Unique Selling Point: Code once, deploy to billions of devices. LiveCode is a truly multi-platform programming tool with iOS, Android, Mac, Windows, Linux, Server & HTML5 deployment options)*.

Any idea's suggestions or plans for porting MergeAV to Android?

Friendly regards,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

check out mergZXingGetBarcode (mergAndroid) at various locations including [mergAndroid Livecode- scanning barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231292/mergandroid-livecode-scanning-barcode)